# Android: FileChooserParams.getFilenameHint() return null. How can I get name of the input?

Tags: java, android, file, input, webview

I'd like to get name of input tag.
[Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)
says getFilenameHint will return the name.
But I got null.

This is sample code of Vue js(web)

```
<input type="file" name="nameTest" title="titleTest" />
```

I need "nameTest".
So, I use below code in onShowFileChooser.

And, this is sample code of Android(java)

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
                String[] deniedPermissions = PermissionUtil.checkDeniedPermissions(getApplicationContext(), needPermissions);
                if (deniedPermissions.length != 0) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, deniedPermissions, PERMISSION_RESULT);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    String inputName = fileChooserParams.getFilenameHint();
                    if (inputName != null) {
                        Log.i("input name", inputName);
                    }
                    imageChooser();
                }
                return true;
            }
```

But, fileChooserParams.getFilenameHint return null.

How can I get name of the input?

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: If you want the name then why do you go for the hint?

Comment: I have several input tag in webView and they work independently.
So, I have to know their id value to control them in native code.